# Question about convergence or divergence of an infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm studying convergence and divergence of infinite sums. I've been working on this but I can't figure it out applying the ratio criterion and the root one. The exercise asks to determine whether it diverges or not. This is the sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$$
Ii've supposed it diverges since it's similar to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your guess is right, to prove that rigorously let apply [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) that is

$$\frac{\frac{(n)(n-1)}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}}{\frac1n}=\frac{(n^2)(n-1)}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}\to 1$$

to conclude that the series diverges.

As an alternative, by direct comparison test we can use that as $n>1$

$$\frac{(n)(n-1)}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} \ge \frac{(n-1)^2}{(n+3)^3}=\left(\frac{n-1}{n+3}\right)^2\frac1{n+3}\ge \frac1{25} \frac1{n+3}$$

Comment: Why not say that you're using an asymptotic equivalent?

Comment: @Bernard We can also state LCT in this way if we prefer if we agree with the underlying proof. I'm just used to refer to it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your second solution is the one I was looking for, i still haven't understood why I haven't thought about it. Again Thanks

Comment: @AlessandroTassoni You are welcome. Note that "similarity" with $\sum 1/n$ is not a rigorous argument, to conclude we need to refer to LCT. As you can see direct comaprison test is often much more subtle and tedious, then don't be afraid to use LCT when needed! Bye

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{n(n-1)}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$$
divide numerator and denominator by $n^3$

$$\frac{\frac{n}{n}\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{n}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{3}{n}\right)}$$
as $n\to\infty$ it is equivalent to $\frac{1}{n}$ which diverges.